# Can't get rid of hardcoded delay even when Explicit Wait is already there

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written some code in python in combination with selenium to parse the different questions from `quora.com`. My scraper is doing it's job at this moment. The thing is I've used here hardcoded delay for the scraper to work, even when `Explicit Wait` has already been defined. As the page is an infinite scrolling one, i tried to make the scrolling process to a limited number. Now, I have got two questions:

1. Why `wait.until(EC.staleness_of(page))` is not working within my scraper. It is commented out now.
2. If i use something else instead of `page = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "question_link")))` the scraper throws an error: `can't focus element`.

Btw, I do not wish to go for `page = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')` this option.

Here is what I've written so far:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.quora.com/topic/C-programming-language")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

page = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "question_link")))
for scroll in range(10):
    page.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(2)
    # wait.until(EC.staleness_of(page))

for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "rendered_qtext"))):
    print(item.text)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code to get as much XHR as possible and then parse the page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.quora.com/topic/C-programming-language")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

page = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "question_link")))
links_counter = len(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "question_link"))))
while True:
    page.send_keys(Keys.END)
    try:
        wait.until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("question_link")) > links_counter)
        links_counter = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("question_link"))
    except TimeoutException:
        break


for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "rendered_qtext"))):
    print(item.text)

driver.quit()
```

Here we scroll page down and wait up to 10 seconds for more links to be loaded or break the `while` loop if the number of links remains the same

As for your questions:

1. `wait.until(EC.staleness_of(page))` is not working because when you scroll page down you don't get the new DOM - you just make XHR which adds more links into existed DOM, so the first link (`page`) will not be stale in this case
2. (I'm not quite confident about this, but...) I guess you can send keys only to nodes that can be focused (user can set focus manually), e.g. links, input fields, textareas, buttons..., but not content division (`div`), paragraphs (`p`), etc

Comment: One thing sir: can you attach here a link to `lambda` function? Willing to get the clarity about this function. Thanks again.

Comment: [Here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function) you can check how to use lambda-function, but I can't find good link for creating custom wait condition with lambda...